# sorting an internal GenericRelation field in Django

Tags: django

I have a model Item with:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    comments = generic.GenericRelation(Comment)
    ...
```

my comment model :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """
    Comment object for any model which want to integrate with the comment engine
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=512)
    user = models.ForeignKey( User )
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In my templete I have something like that and I set in the templete context Items as Item.objects.all():

```
{% for item in Items %} 
     {%for comment in item.comments.all %}
          <p> comment.comment</p>
     {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

What I would really like is that the comments will be all sorted by created_date per Item. How can I set how to sort an internal genericRelation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a model's meta class

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    # attrs
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_date']
```

or use a manager which is slightly verbose in your case

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CommentManager, self).get_queryset().order_by('created_date')


class Comment(models.Model):
    # attrs
    objects = CommentManager()
```

More on managers across relationships:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types